# What is an accessible book about plant evolution for a non-biologist?

Tags: evolution, botany, literature, life-history

I have an acquaintance interested in learning about the evolution history of plants. This person has a wide knowledge on botanics, from personal reading and taking care of plants, but E is neither a biologist or a biology student.

Based on this, which is an accessible book to non-biologist that can be used to learn about the evolution of plants?

Comment: Can you please provide additional details like: what extent of information do you expect, what topics should it cover etc. If a person is a non-biologist then they can simply start with a general book on evolution. There are many popular books for non-biologists (or even non-scientists). [This website](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/home.php) is also a good place to start. Unfortunately, the answer to your question would highly depend on the personal opinions of people. Unless you ask very specific recommendations, literature suggestions would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I have Fossil Plants by Paul Kenrick and Paul Davis, published by The Natural History Museum in London.  It takes the reader through a well-researched but accessible illustrated history of the evolution of plantlife from the beginnings to now.  There are photos of many key fossils, and artist's renderings of what the landscapes of the past would have looked like.

Comment: It is possible to download it as a pdf from researchgate. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248686492_P_Kenrick_P_Davis_2004_Fossil_Plants_216_pp_London_The_Natural_History_Museum_Price_1695_paperback_ISBN_0_565_09176_X

Comment: @John, that is a review of the book, not the book.

Comment: So it is, my mistake, still helpful so I'll leave the link.